# .select() not functioning correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'll keep it short and sweet. Trying to implement .select in jQuery and it doesn't seem to be cooperating in Chrome. Clicking in to the input selects the contents only briefly.

```
$(document).on('focus','.a-thing', function () {
    this.select();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Hhh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a jQuery object

```
$(document).on({
    focus : function () {
        $(this).select();
    },
    mouseup : function() {
        return false;
    }    
}, '.a-thing');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Hhh/6/)

And you have to prevent the `mouseup` event to avoid loosing the selection as the mouseup event deselects the text, it's a know issue in Chrome.

Comment: @TusharGupta - It does, but then you're using the native `text.select()` method, and not the jQuery method [select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/). There *is* a difference, but in this case it wouldn't really matter.

Comment: Probably bad practice nonetheless. I know $(this) is proper but I also knew .this just worked for what I was doing. I did not however know the difference/implications of using it. Thanks.

Comment: @TusharGupta [Input.select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.select)

Comment: @RGraham I am asking difference between `this.select()` vs `$(this).select();`. adeneo pointed there is a difference .

Comment: Those are two completely different functions, but again, in this case they do the same thing. The question asked for ".select in jQuery", and I'm guessing jQuery's version is *more* cross browser, but it seems like the native one is supported in all five browsers as well, so it's probably not that important when you're not using any of the added arguments in the jQuery version.

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to using the focus event. Try to fire the select event *after* the focus is complete:

```
$(document).on('focus','.a-thing', function () {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.select();    
    },1);
});
```

[<kbd>Updated jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/BaYV4/)

Comment: +1 . FYI minimum delay is `4 ms` even if you pass less .

Comment: @TusharGupta Interesting, didn't realise this

Comment: @Glancey - click is not a substitute for the focus event.

Comment: @adeneo - Is there some glaring compatibility issue I might be missing?

Comment: @Glancey - Not really, but there's no guarantee that a click will give an element focus, and an element can receive focus without being clicked, so using a click handler is not a substitute for a focus handler, even if it would probably work for most cases.

Comment: @adeneo Thinking about it there is a rather obvious one. It's rather annoying to click the text cursor to a specific place in the string when `select` is firing on `click`. Bad UX. This isn't a problem with `focus`.

Answer (score 1):

User `click` event instead of `foucs`, because keyboard tab key will auto select field value without `foucs` event

```
$(document).on('click','.a-thing', function () {
    this.select();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Hhh/3/)

Comment: +1 for technically achieving what I wanted but `click` makes it difficult for users to click to specific points in the text (ie for the purpose of editing) after already having focused the element.

Comment: @Glancey, `click` event is binding input element, so if you click anywhere in `input` element then also it would work fine.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you should try the jsFiddle you provided. It seems to be impossible to click anywhere inside the input without selecting the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can active the select on the mouse up instead of the focus. Chrome seems to de-select on the mouse up event.

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.a-thing', function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

Or if you want to keep the focus event, you can prevent the action on mouse up

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.a-thing', function () {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On mouseup event the selection is getting unselected, Please add the following to fix the issue

```
$(".a-thing").mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/WnhaK/)**